# How do I use the 'Blocklisted User Input' information page?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, blocked-tags

The Blocklisted User Input page found under Moderator Tools is as barren and non-descript as the [/reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation) page. There are a few read-only entries, so presumably the entries can only be edited by an administrator/SE employee.

How useful is it to a moderator if he/she doesn't know what it does?

(Note: Previously called 'Blacklisted User Input')

Comment: You can kinda tell what's been blacklisted (if you have at least a passing knowledge of Regex).  That's about it.  If you don't know what it does, it's not useful at all.

Comment: I agree with Robert.  The only thing I've ever used it for is to see what's there and suggest changes to devs.  I'd absolutely *love* to have edit privileges, but apparently it would be costly to blacklist all the things.

Comment: Does it blacklist words or tags?

Comment: @Ambo100 It can do both.  Under the 'type' column I see entries of both 'Tag' and 'Universal' on SO.  That way some things can be blacklisted in tags *only* (programming, subjective, offtopic) and others can be blacklisted in titles, bodies, tags, etc.

Comment: @Laurel Does that page really say "Blocklisted" instead of blocked? We do realize that anyone who tries to search for that term on a major search engine will have their search "corrected" to "blacklisted" right? I support changing the term, but "blocklisted" is not the right thing to change it to.

Comment: @ColleenV That's what it [says in the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pp6r.jpg). It's a common term now in software development, at least. Also, anyone who's searching for the old name will find this post because I put it in the body. It's an especially weird name because not all all the tags there are blocked — tags with "tag tips" or "tag warnings" are also on that page.

Comment: It's not a common enough term to appear in English learner's dictionaries. I'm not criticizing you for updating the title, I am just kind of annoyed at how jargony SE is getting. It's not a good replacement. It looks like a typo. If I replace 'slur' with 'slor' and every dictionary returns 'slur', am I really changing it? 
 https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=blocklisted https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/spellcheck/learner-english/?q=blocklisted https://www.ldoceonline.com/spellcheck/english/?q=blocklisted

Answer (score 4):

Blacklisted tags show up here; I've noticed "tag" and "intrinsic tag". "Best Practices" is blacklisted on UX because it's a useless tag; it applies to pretty much every question except the dark-patterns and anti-patterns questions. "UX" and "UI" are blocked as "intrinsic" tags because they apply to almost everything in the subject matter.

Some input like spam URLs is blocked with the note "universal", I think those are SE-wide blocks because of cross-site spam.

As a mod you can't add something to the list directly, but you can ask the community team to block spam URLs or blacklist a tag if it's a *serious* problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to request a specific item to be blacklisted, you could theoretically look there if it is already implemented.

In practice, there is no reason for a moderator to ever visit that site beyond idle curiosity, I'd just ignore this page. The blacklist is really a developer tool, not a tool for moderators.

The main action moderators take with regard to blacklists, is requesting a new item for the list. You don't need to see the existing items to do that, usually.

Answer (score 2):

The only cases when you would look at that page are:

- You need to ask a tag to be black-listed, and you check it is already black-listed. (It is possible to black-list more tags using regular expressions).
- Somebody asked for a tag to be black-listed, and you want to check it is already black-listed, to mark the request as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).
- Somebody is adding a tag, but he cannot; he asked a question on the meta site, and you look at that page to see if it has been black-listed.

> How useful is it to a moderator if he/she doesn't know what it does?

If the moderator doesn't know what a black-listed tag is, s/he will probably not find that page useful.

Comment: Potentially covered by those cases, but sometimes a tag-block request is marked as done, but then the tag seemingly comes back. In those cases, it can be helpful to check that the tag block was actually implemented in a way that would block the problematic tag. (I've encountered one case where a supposedly "blocked" tag seemingly reappeared on a site - and it turned out that the regex used for the tag block wasn't actually set up in a way that would prevent the problem tag from being created again.)